# how to insert all id with similar text in a list with selinium python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

```
<div>
 <div id="ide_1"> </div>
 <div id="ide_3"> </div>
 <div id="ide_5"> </div>
 <div id="ide_7"> </div>
</div>
```

I want to select all ids of the child div and insert them in a list but i didn't find any solution to get into the parent div. I am trying to find  all id that's similar to `ide_` because that's the fix part which wouldn't change.

Comment: does the main div tag have any other attributes ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `css_selector` search for all ids that contains `ide_`

```
find_elements_by_css_selector('[id*="ide_"]')
```

Comment: this isn't the content value of the id 
i've try this example 
x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id*="_ariaId_137"]')

this is the value of x 
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="5846a441-60ae-4c32-b
892-459867abdf0f", element="{1b661b90-6da4-4b60-882b-318493a5104d}")>]

Comment: @sala.eddi This is list of `WebElements`. To get the id iterate over it and use `get_attribute("id") on each element`

Comment: `find_elements_by_css_selector('[id*="ide_"]')`

this peace of code work for me fine but, if i want to look for similar id but in a specific div located by css class 
is that possible?

Comment: @sala.eddi It is. Add the `div` locator to the `css_selector`. For example if the `div` has class `some_class` you can locate it with `find_elements_by_css_selector('.some_class [id*="ide_"]')`

Comment: Ok my bad i didn't explian the issue well enough, the div with css class some_class  is the container div of another div which containt the similar  id 'ide_' that i'm looking for.
is there any way to do that

Comment: @sala.eddi This will work. The space between `.some_class` and `[id*="ide_"]` means any descendant of element with class `some_class` that has id with `ide_`.

Comment: Just replace `.some_class` with the correct locator

Comment: `y = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('._lvv_Y1 [id*="ide_"]')`

yes i did that but y is totally empty

`print len(y)`
output 0

Comment: @sala.eddi Can tou post the html of the `div` tag you want?

Comment: `<div class="myclass" style="height: 129450px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; bottom: auto; top: 1620px;">
<div>
<div id="_ariaId_970" tabindex="-1"></div>
<div id="_ariaId_3" tabindex="-1"></div>
<div id="_ariaId_4" tabindex="-1"></div>
<div id="_ariaId_5" tabindex="-1"></div>
<div id="_ariaId_14" tabindex="-1"></div>
<div id="_ariaId_77" tabindex="-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="-1"></div>
 </div>
</div>`
this my code i want only div with the id ide_  but located in the div with class myclass

Comment: @sala.eddi in the html example the code should be `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.myclass [id*="_ariaId"]')`

Comment: Is `_lvv_Y1 ` full class name? or partial? if it's partial it should be `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class*="_lvv_Y1"] [id*="ide_"]')`

Comment: it didn't work for me I've try this and it work fine 
`lvv = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('._lvv_Y1')`
then the container div 
`parrent = lvv[0].find_elements_by_xpath("div")`

then i get ids that i want 
`c = parrent[0].find_elements_by_css_selector('[id*="_ariaId_"]')`

thanks for your time @guy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **find_elements_by_xpath()** , this will return a list of elements with specified path.

Lets say your div is located as

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form>
   <table>
    <div>
```

Then you have to specify as

```
driver.find_elements _by_xpath(r'html/body/form/table/div')
```

In case if you have any classname or any text or anything in the main **div** element you can Use any of the **find_elements** method . for further reading [Locating Elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: That's the main  problem, there nothing to count on to select the parent div  just that  similarity of all ids in all child div

Comment: i try to copy the xpath location with firebug and this is what i get 

html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]